# Treetag package koRpus R

Tags: r, lemmatization, treetagger, korpus

First, I'm sorry for my English, I speak very bad English.

So, I have a question about treetag function from koRpus package on R. 
I want to lemmatized a text and it's ok for me with Treetagger. 
I used the treetag function :

```
treetag(file, treetagger = "manual", lang = "fr",
        TT.options = list(path, preset="fr"))
```

I obtained tokens, tags...

But after this Lemmatization, I want to obtained the tagged text and I have not solution to do this. I want to replace in my text, each token by his lemma.

So, Have you a solution for me ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

```
Proof next steps:

txt1 <- treetag(c(“played”, “saw”),
treetagger=”manual”, lang=”en”,
encoding = “UTF-8″,
TT.options=list(path=”C:/TreeTagger”, preset=”en”),
format = “obj”)

text2 <- slot(txt1 , "TT.res")

text3<- ifelse(text2$lemma == "<unknown>", text2 $token, 
                           text2$lemma)
```